# How can I subtract 2 string or list in python?

Tags: python, string, list, difference, subtraction

I have very large strings in my codes. I would like to detect different characters between the strings. Here is an example what I mean:

```
 a='ababaab'
 b='abaaaaa'
 a=a-b
 print(a)
```

I expect kind of like these; 'bb' or '000b00b'

I know sounds weird but I really need this.

Comment: So you want all the chars in `a` that are different at the same position in `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
a = 'ababaab'
b = 'abaaaaa'

a = ''.join(x if x != y else '0' for x, y in zip(a, b))
# '000b00b'
# OR
a = ''.join(x for x, y in zip(a, b) if x != y)
# 'bb'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example: It works wih list

```
listA = ["a","b"]
listB = ["b", "c"]
listC = [item for item in listB if item not in listA]
print listC
```

Output

```
# ['c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom function as following:
(assumption length of both strings are equal)

```
def str_substract(str1, str2):
    res = ""
    for _ in xrange(len(str1)):
        if str1[_] != str2[_]:
            res += str1[_]
        else:
            res += "0"
    return res

a='ababaab'
b='abaaaaa'

print str_substract(a, b)
```

**output:**

```
000b00b
```

Comment: Which library you used for xrange?

Comment: Why are you using an `_` as the looping variable, when it is conventionally used for a *throw-away* variable? Also, this will be *extremely* inefficient, using `+=` with `str` objects will give you quadratic complexity.

Comment: @VuralErdogan it's Python 2 equivalent to Python 3 `range`

Answer (score 0):

```
result = ''

for temp in a:
    result += temp if temp not in b else '0'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip`:

```
res = ''
for i, j in zip(a, b):
     if i == j:
         res += '0'
     else:
         res += i
```

Using a list to store the result is probably more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

if you want `s1 - s2` :

```
   s1 = 'ababaab'
    s2 = 'abaaaaa'



   for i,j in zip(s1,s2):
        if (i != j):
            print i,
```

output :  `bb`